# Вернуть старое окно настройки графика Matplotlib (subplot configuration tool)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Раньше при открытии окна графика можно было нажатием на соответствующий значок открыть меню дополнительных параметров (для движения графика влево/вправо и т.п.).

После переустановки системы (т.е. и Python вместе с библиотеками) это окно изменилось и стало менее удобным и функциональным. Сейчас это бегунки (см. фото), а раньше были блоки для ввода коэффициентов, были дополнительные кнопки, например, выполнения `tight_layout` при уже созданном и отображенном графике

**Как вернуть старый вид этого окна?**[image: Новый вид окна]

Comment: Нашел в интернете изображение, как оно выглядело раньше:
https://image01.seesaawiki.jp/m/n/met-python/b5e2c96883c1c1ad.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не тот «backend», который был в предыдущей версии (предположительно `Qt4Agg` из картинки в вашем комментарии).

Существуют многие бекенды (напр. QtAgg, Gtk4Agg, Gtk3Agg, TkAgg, WxAgg, Qt5Agg, ...), но не все в каждой системе.

Из картинки мне кажется, что вы работаете в IPython. Попробуйте применить команду

```
%matplotlib
```

(которая переключит на стандартный бекенд) перед тем, как построить график.

Когда это будет работать, как вы хотели, вы можете перманентно включить этот бекенд в конфигурационном файле `matplotlibrc`, или в переменной окружения `MPLBACKEND`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Я понял в чем проблема, на прошлой системе у меня было установлено PyQt5. При его наличии matplotlib автоматически переходит на него. Решается то всего-лишь с помощью ```pip install PyQt5```. Спасибо!

Comment: @astronom.v.cube, не стоит, наконец вы сами справились с этим. Удачи вам!